# What are the advantages of using Inline Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inline

I know that Inline Javascript hasn't got many benefits but I would still like to know a couple positives of embedding scripts in the HTML of web pages.Thanks!

Comment: The only benefit I can think of is it saves a request to an external js file.

Comment: The browser doesn't need to make a HTTP request to fetch a script, so HTML parsing is not blocked on network. As Quentin's answer says, caching is often a better solution for this.

Comment: Do you mean "inline" as in `<script>...</script>` (rather than `<script src="..">`) or do you mean actually inline with the html itself, as in `<button onclick="somejavascript()">`?

Answer (score 3):

- It doesn't require an additional HTTP request. (Independent caching is usually more valuable though, and HTTP 2 / SPDY  will render the cost of additional requests moot.)
- It can been distributed as a single file in lieu of hosting on a real URL (but that's irrelevant on the WWW).

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!

Comment: Does this mean developers shouldn't use inline scripts nowaday?

Comment: @Tresdin — It means that the advantages of external scripts will, more often than not, dramatically outweigh the benefits of inline scripts.